# Minimum Arc-length in a surface.

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, arc-length

Imagine a particle is confinded onto a surface. The only rule that the partcle follows is always choosing the path that minimizes the lenght of travel.

$$
\boldsymbol{\mathrm r}(\tau) =  u(\tau) \; \boldsymbol{\mathrm e_1} + v(\tau) \; \boldsymbol{\mathrm e_2}  + w(\tau) \; \boldsymbol{\mathrm e_3}
$$

If we wanna find the arclength.
$$
\mathrm d s^2 = \mathrm d \boldsymbol{\mathrm r} \cdot\mathrm d \boldsymbol{\mathrm r} \\
S = \int_{\partial \mathcal M} \sqrt{\mathrm d \boldsymbol{\mathrm r} \cdot\mathrm d \boldsymbol{\mathrm r}} \\
S = \int_{\partial \mathcal M} {\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm d \boldsymbol{\mathrm r}}{\mathrm d \tau} \cdot \frac{\mathrm d \boldsymbol{\mathrm r}}{\mathrm d \tau}} \; \mathrm d \tau} = \int_{\partial \mathcal M} {\frac{\mathrm d \mathrm r } {\mathrm d \tau} \; \mathrm d \tau} =  \int_{\partial \mathcal M} { \dot{\mathrm r} \; \mathrm d \tau} 
$$
And now vary and find the functional that minimizes the arclenght:
$$
\delta S = \int_{\partial \mathcal M} { \delta \dot{\mathrm r} \; \mathrm d \tau}  = 0\\
\delta \dot{\mathcal r} = \left | \frac{\mathrm d \dot{\boldsymbol {\mathrm r}}}{\mathrm d \tau} \right | \delta \tau \\
\delta S = \int_ {\partial \mathcal M} { \left | \frac{\mathrm d \dot{\boldsymbol {\mathrm r}}}{\mathrm d \tau} \right | \delta \tau \; \mathrm d \tau} = 0 \\
\therefore \left | \frac{\mathrm d \dot{\boldsymbol {\mathrm r}}}{\mathrm d \tau} \right | = 0
$$
This means that the $\boldsymbol{\mathrm r}$ is a straight line, thing that make sense. But what a about a particle that is confined to a curved surface. How would you find this function that minimizes arclenght? Do I have to take into account the basis vectors tangent to the surfaces, or the gradient?

Comment: You're essentially asking for the theory of geodesics...?

Comment: Short answer: the first formula for $S$ is no longer correct on curved surfaces.

Comment: How would you correct this formula? Could someone show me how to derive this function that minimizes lenght?

Comment: In your integration formulas you have written $\int_\mathcal M$. What is $\mathcal M$?

Comment: The bounds of integration. Maybe I shall write it as: $\partial \mathcal M$

Comment: It appears to me you're conflating $\frac{dr}{d\tau}$ and $\left| \frac{d\bf{r}}{d\tau}\right|$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I used $\boldsymbol{\mathrm r}$ and $\mathrm r$ to distinguish between the vector and the norm.

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodrigo as is common convention. But the two objects in my comment *are* distinct. $\sqrt{\frac{d\bf{r}}{d\tau} \cdot \frac{d\bf{r}}{d\tau}} = \left|\frac{d\bf{r}}{d\tau}\right|$, not $\frac{d|\bf{r}|}{d\tau}$.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Riemannian_geometry) is the theory you are looking for in short. For more details, search for introductions to Riemannian geometry. To correct your formula, you have to replace the Euclidean distance formula $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$ with a metric tensor that measures distance along the surface.